# C: GCC compiler—conflicting types error

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a program that I've copied verbatim from my textbook, but I get the following error:

`maxline.c:4:5: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
/usr/include/stdio.h:675:20: note: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here
maxline.c:26:5: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
/usr/include/stdio.h:675:20: note: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here`

Here are the lines in question:

```
4 int getline(char line[], int maxline);

26 int getline(char s[], int lim)
```

Is there something incredibly obvious that I've missed?

Comment: Why do lines 4 and 26 use different names for the parameters? It's not illegal, but it's odd.

Comment: Note you didn't post the decl in `stdio.h`, which is the *real* point of conflict. Obviously both *your* decl and implementation should match each other. The warning is telling you `getline()` is already declared, and doesn't match *your* code (either the prototype or the definition). Look at *that* decl (in stdio.h, line 675).

Comment: Worked perfectly when I changed the name of "getline" to "getln." Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getline` is declared in `stdio.h`. It's not specified by the ISO C standard, but it is specified as an extension, originally by GNU and later by POSIX. `man getline` for more information on the predefined `getline` function, or see the [official POSIX description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).

You've declared your own function with the same name, which apparently conflicts with the declaration in `stdio.h`, which probably looks something like this (omitting the `restrict` qualifiers to save space):

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

Either use a different name for your function (`get_line` would work), or compile your code with options that make the `stdio.h` version of `getline` invisible -- probably something like `-std=c99 -pedantic`.